# how to add string to array and delete special character

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi See My Example i want to split `;` from string. i have string

"hello;hi;hey" and i have sperated it to

```
array[0]=hello;
array[1]=hi;
array[2]=hey;
```

My Question Is Delete " `;` " And Then Add Each Of Them(hello hi and hey) To Array "programmatically" Like Top
I Know it's too easy but i couldn't find it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Look at string.Split

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to *split* the string :

```
string[] array = "hello;hi;hey".Split(';');
// array[0] -> "hello"
// array[1] -> "hi"
// array[2] -> "hey"
```

Comment: @HosseinJfp note that this doesn't keep the character you split on in the string. So the results will be, `array[0]=="hello"`, not `array[0]=="hello;"`, the second of which is what your question stated you wanted.

Comment: @HosseinJfp ah I see that comment now. Just making sure you don't end up with rogue characters in the wrong spots.

Comment: @HosseinJfp If the answer is correct you should mark it as correct answer (and not only upvote) by *accepting* the answer.